# How to change storage class of existing key via boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

When using AWS S3 service, I need to change storage class of existing key from STANDARD to STANDARD_IA.

`change_storage_class` from boto doesn't exist in boto3.

What is the equivalent in Boto3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from [amazon doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ChgStoClsOfObj.html)

> You can also change the storage class of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3 by copying it to the same key name in the same bucket. To do that, you use the following request headers in a PUT Object copy request:
>
> - `x-amz-metadata-directive` set to `COPY`
> - `x-amz-storage-class` set to `STANDARD`, `STANDARD_IA`, or `REDUCED_REDUNDANCY`

in term of boto3 [copy code](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object), this will look like

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}

s3.copy(
  copy_source, 'mybucket', 'mykey',
  ExtraArgs = {
    'StorageClass': 'STANDARD_IA',
    'MetadataDirective': 'COPY'
  }
)
```

Comment: will this work even if the file is beyond 5GB in size?

Comment: @VarunSingh yes, the `copy` method is a managed transfer. If the file is beyond 5GB in size, then it will use the multipart copy in multiple threads if necessary.

Comment: @JohnBissonette I know is long ago, but thanks for clarifying. I will try this out.

Comment: Does this read the data to the client and write it back, or is the operation internal to S3?