# How to use boto3 to write to S3 standard infrequent access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I searched in the [boto3 doc](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but didn't find relevant information there. In this [link](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3359), it is mentioned that it can be done using

`k.storage_class='STANDARD_IA'`

Can someone share a full code snippet here? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you wish to set that storage class at the time that the object is created, or after it is created?

Comment: Could you show me both ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [boto3 Storing Data](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#storing-data) example, it looks like the standard way to put objects in `boto3` is

```
s3.Object('mybucket', 'hello.txt').put(Body=open('/tmp/hello.txt', 'rb'))
```

But to set the storage class, [S3.Object.Put](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put) suggests we'd want to use parameter:

```
StorageClass='STANDARD_IA'
```

So combining the two, we have:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('mybucket', 'hello.txt').put(Body=open('/tmp/hello.txt', 'rb'), StorageClass='STANDARD_IA')
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 16):

**New file**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

client.upload_file(
    Filename = '/tmp/foo.txt', 
    Bucket = 'my-bucket', 
    Key = 'foo.txt',
    ExtraArgs = {
      'StorageClass': 'STANDARD_IA'
    }
)
```

**Existing file**

From [How to change storage class of existing key via boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310975/174777):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}

s3.copy(
  CopySource = copy_source,
  Bucket = 'target-bucket', 
  Key = 'target-key',
  ExtraArgs = {
    'StorageClass': 'STANDARD_IA',
    'MetadataDirective': 'COPY'
  }
)
```

Comment: also see- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.93/reference/services/s3/object/copy_from.html