# Archive S3 files to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-glacier

I have a scenario where I am fetching the data from AWS-S3 file and writing back to postgresql. Once this task is completed I want to archive this file to AWS Glacier. Is there any possibility to write any Glue Job or Lambda Function for this. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change the [Storage Class](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) of the object to `GLACIER` or `DEEP_ARCHIVE`.

This actually requires that the Amazon S3 object be 'copied over itself', with the storage class changed.

See: [How to change storage class of existing key via boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310975/174777)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I need to change the storage class only when the file is written to PostgreSQL. If the file is not written then it shouldn't change the storage class.

Comment: Yes, your script/program should call the copy command to change the storage class when desired. For example, an AWS Lambda function can call the command.